# Android mosby Access to view from presenter

Tags: android, mosby

I would like to access to view widgets such as `TextView` or `EditText` from presenter, how can i do that,

in my activity main i want to change `scheduleDateTimeNotify` text from presenter

```
public class ActivityChannelContent extends MvpActivity<ActivityChannelContentView, ActivityChannelContentPresenter>
        implements ActivityChannelContentView{

    @BindView(R.id.scheduleDateTimeNotify)
    TextView scheduleDateTimeNotify;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ActivityChannelContentPresenter createPresenter() {
        return new ActivityChannelContentPresenterImpl(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel_content);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public interface ActivityChannelContentPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ActivityChannelContentView> {
}
```

ActivityChannelContentPresenterImpl:

```
public class ActivityChannelContentPresenterImpl extends MvpBasePresenter<ActivityChannelContentView> implements ActivityChannelContentPresenter {
    private final ActivityChannelContentModel model;

    public ActivityChannelContentPresenterImpl(Context context) {
        model = new ActivityChannelContentModel(context);
    }
}
```

ActivityChannelContentViewModel:

```
public class ActivityChannelContentViewModel {
    private final Context context;

    public ActivityChannelContentViewModel(Context mContext) {
        context = mContext;
    }
}
```

ActivityChannelContentView interface:

```
public interface ActivityChannelContentView extends MvpView {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on MVP design pattern and you can set text on TextView in View with using Presenter logic. For example:

```
public interface MContract {

    interface View{
        void setText(String value)
    }

    interface Presenter extends BasePresenter {
        void addData(String value);
    }
}

public class MPresenter implements MContract.Presenter {
    private MContract.View mView;

    @Override
    public void addData(String value) {
            mView.setText(value);
    }
}

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity  implements MContract.View {

 @Override
    public void setText(String value) {textview.setText(value);}
}
```

Comment: this solution is not based on `mosby`

Comment: @NimishaV `private MContract.View mView;` - How did you instantiate mView?